# Intellisense ctrl+space in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2010, intellisense, visual-c++-2010

I'm writing a small program using CLR console application and when I write something it doesn't give suggestions, although i press (Ctrl+Space). I'm using visual studio 2010
can any one help me?

Comment: Just tested it here. I don't get it either. I have a brand new VS2010 installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Visual C++ 2010 does not have IntelliSense for C++/CLI.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/03/09/intellisense-browsing-options-in-vc-2010.aspx)

Comment: The comments on that blog are funny. Including people saying they'd take MS to court for taking features out.